# error: out of bounds when searching for identical rows in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, rows, equals

Given a numpy array of 2300 rows and 44 columns, I'd like my script to check for equal rows and to return arrays of those equal rows with the according indices in the original matrix.

Example:

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0
1 2 3 4 5
```

Result:

```
equal_arrays1 = [1,2,3]
equal_arrays2 = [0,4]
```

My original data set consists of zero rows starting from 1323 to 1699. The result should then be:

```
equal_array1=[1323,...,1699]
```

What I did up till now is using the following code:

```
import numpy as np


input_data = np.load('1IN.npy')
print(np.shape(input_data))

for i in range(len(input_data)):
   for j in range(i+1,len(input_data)):
      if np.array_equal(input_data[i],input_data[j]):
          if np.array_equal(input_data[:,i],input_data[:,j]):
           print (i, j),
      else: break
```

but this led to the error:

```
if np.array_equal(input_data[:,i],input_data[:,j])   :

IndexError: index 1302 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 44
```

I think that this is not the best way to go for what I want to achieve, so if anyone has a better alternative or could explain what I need to fix, I'd be glad as I'm new to python.

Comment: You know that this cannot work: `input_data[:,i],input_data[:,j]`, right? the array is not square, so if you do that. you are going to be out of the 44 column. Not sure why this line is there is you are comparing rows.

Comment: I think I see what you re telling me, so do you have a suggestion on how to change it?

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering why you need that check? Rows are equals, why do you need to check columns? If there is no reason, just remove the check.

Comment: I did not intend to check columns, only rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check only rows, so remove the check on column equality:

```
matching_pairs = []

for i in range(len(input_data)):
   for j in range(i+1,len(input_data)):
      if np.array_equal(input_data[i],input_data[j]):
         matching_pairs.append((i, j))
         # break?

print(matching_pairs)
```

Not sure what the break is about? You may want to break if you found a `j` matching your `i`, but you don't want to break if you don't find it, otherwise you will only check `i` against `i+1` and nothing more.

Comment: Is there a way to display the equal rows in an array like I mentioned in the example? Like this: equal_array1=[1323,...,1699]

Comment: Here we go, edit to save the list of pairs and print them after.

Comment: i.e. now that you have the list of equal rows, you can process them and display whatever you want.

Comment: One more thing: I ran the code, it's working (thank you!) but the problem is that it saves tuples (i,j). I'd rather have arrays that list the indices of the equal rows, as mentioned in the example, with equal_arrays1=[1,2,3], equal_arrays2=[0,4]. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, just change the save code to `equal_arrays1.append(i)` and `equal_arrays2.append(j)` isntead of just one statement.

Comment: one last thing: This is how a part of equal_arrays1 looks like: [1302, 1302, 1302, 1303, 1303, 1304, 1323, 1323, 1323, 1323, 1323, 1323, 1323, 1323, ...  as you can see the same indices are listed several times and also Im having runtime problems with the script. Do you think the code can be improved in that sense? Right now, the script checks if two rows are the same, but I'd rather have it check if n rows are the same and then add the indices together into one array.

Comment: yes, because we are always checking against `i` first, so if there are 3 similar rows, then `i` will have twice the same value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185163/discussion-between-dorian-il-and-matthieu-brucher).